# Appending a @ character to an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to concatenate two strings with NSString initWithFormat, and I am getting garbage output. Here is my code:

```
userLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%s",[[tweets objectAtIndex:0] screen_name]];
```

The output should be something like this - "@username", while at the moment it is coming out like this - "@`;á". Is there an escape sequence I need to use to display an @ symbol correctly in an NSString?

Comment: [Pedantic nitpick: When you're adding it before the string, it's "prepending". ;)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `screen_name` is an `NSString`, use `"@%@"` format. The `%s` format is for C strings.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was forgetting :)

Answer (score 2):

What's the type of your screen_name? If it's a `NSString` instance you need use `%@` instead of `%s`. Like:

`userLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[[tweets objectAtIndex:0] screen_name]];`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the unicode value escape sequence: `\u0040`